# PHP: how to use usort with anonymous function?

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array of array.

I'm trying this code to sort main array based of a field of every single element of the main array.

```
$field = $this->sorting;
usort($this->out_table["rows"], function($a, $b) use ($field) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$field], $b[$field]);
});
```

But I got this

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION
```

Referred to the second line, the one which starts with 'usort'

What am I missing?

My php version is

```
PHP 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.27 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Mar 11 2013 14:14:48)
```

Comment: What PHP version are you running? Ensure it's `>= 5.30` http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: I've added pvp version in the question

Comment: PHP 5.2 doesn't support anonymous functions. Anonymous functions are instances of the `Closure` class, which [as the docs say](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.construct.php), wasn't introduced until 5.3... PS: _upgrade your PHP version, 5.2 was EOL'ed ages ago

Comment: I cannot upgrade, the server is not mine ! See the Ubuntu version ! i'm so sad... ok, i'll call a class function

Comment: Why someone has downvoted? Cannot a user doesn't know where Closures where introducted? If I have all the infos, I don't ask here !

Comment: @realtebo I didn't downvote, but maybe because it was a case of RTFM? Who knows...

Comment: @hd: Who downvotes without explaining the reason should loose 100 reputation point at a time.... I had no idea of so recent introduction of closures, and so ... I had no idea of what must I read on TFM.... Stackoverflow is coming to be a so aggressive place like some linux specialist forums...

Comment: @realtebo yep. But I didn't downvote so it was purely speculation.

Comment: @realtebo: Relax... hd was the first person to take the time and write an answer to this question, _and_ he took the time to explain why one might -1 this question, too. Don't take it out on him, he's only trying to help...

Comment: @realtebo: *"so recent introduction of closures"*... PHP 5.3 was released [almost 6 years ago](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0). It was even retired in the meantime ([6 months ago](http://php.net/eol.php)). I won't say that the closures were introduced quite recent...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP 5.2 doesn't support anonymous functions. Anonymous functions are instances of the `Closure` class, which [as the docs say](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.construct.php), wasn't introduced until 5.3... PS: _upgrade your PHP version, 5.2 was EOL'ed ages ago.

For now, though, you're best off writing your own class, pass the `$field` value to that class' instance and use the array-style callable argument:

```
class Sorter
{
    protected $field = null;
    public function __construct($field)
    {
        $this->field = $field;
    }
    public function sortCallback($a, $b)
    {
        return strnatcmp($a[$this->field], $b[$this->field]);
    }
}
$sorter = new Sorter($field);
usort($this->out_table["rows"], array($sorter, 'sortCallback'));
```

Which is basically what a `Closure` instance does, the anonymous function business is syntactic sugar in this case. The advantage of a class like this is that you *could* add some more sort-callbacks to it, and keep it handy as a sort of utility class with a `sortAscending` and `sortDescending` callback method, for example. Along with options you can set on the instance that make the sorter use strict (type and value) comparison where it's needed....

Comment: Removed my answer because I prefer this way.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ: You didn't have to delete your answer. Seeing as some people might be reluctant to implement my suggested fix (people who don't like/know/use OOP do exist). To them, and because it is, technically, valid, your answer is fine. Especially because, to me at least, it demonstrates the value of OOP => not having to use `global` and such...

Comment: I didn't think of it that way :) Personally I dislike `global` and wish for OP to accept this answer because of the potential downfalls `global` introduces.

Answer (score 4):

The [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) were introduced in PHP 5.3.

If you are stuck with an older version of PHP you have to use the function [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php). It produces an anonymous function too, there is no functional difference, only the syntax is not that nice and there is no equivalent for the functionality of `use`:

```
$field = $this->sorting;
usort(
    $this->out_table["rows"],
    create_function(
        // the list of arguments
        '$a, $b',
        // the function body (everything you normally put between { and }
        'global $field; return strnatcmp($a[$field], $b[$field]);'
    )
);
```

To avoid using `global` (it doesn't even work if you put this code in a function/method) you could try to write a function that gets `$field` as argument and creates the comparison function (similar with Javascript closures).

This is easy to do (but not needed) using anonymous functions and can be done with little work using `create_function()` too (it needs escaping, though):

```
function fn($fld)
{
    $fld = addslashes($fld);
    return create_function(
        '$a, $b',                                          // arguments
        "return strnatcmp(\$a['$fld'], \$b['$fld']);"      // function body
    );
}

usort($this->out_table["rows"], fn($field));
```

The function `fn()` basically creates the anonymous function from your code in an old PHP fashion (pre 5.3).

Note that, because the body of the comparison function is generated using the content of argument `$fld`, for some values of `$fld` it can produce runtime errors (compilation errors, in fact, but because the body of the generated function is created and parsed at the runtime, they cannot be detected until it's too late).

Another option, better than `create_function()`, is to create a class for this purpose, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28721535/4265352).

Answer (score 1):

As [per the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), anonymous functions were introduced at version 5.30. You're running lower than 5.30.

- Either upgrade your PHP version (backup server first)
- Use the solution below

```
usort($this->out_table["rows"], 'mySort');
function mySort($a, $b) {
    global $field;
    return strnatcmp($a[$field], $b[$field]);
}
```

Comment: A bit pedantic, perhaps, but `global $field` is IMHO just ugly. A `Sorter` utility class with an `sortAscending` and `sortDescending` method might be more useful to the OP

Comment: Absolutely! I actually favour your answer and would advise not to use `global`.

Comment: +1 to counter the anonymous down-vote, and because of the added value of this answer I told you about in the previous comment

Comment: This code doesn't even work for many reasons. One of them: function [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) is already defined by PHP, one cannot define it again. Then the function is called only once with the undefined parameters `$a` and `$b` before `usort()` even starts. It should read `usort($this->out_table["rows"], 'my_sort'); function my_sort(...)`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I am the down-voter. I exposed the reasons in my previous comment. How many errors should contain an answer to be eligible for down-voting, in your opinion?

Comment: Thanks guys. I understand the reasoning behind the downvote and shouldn't have rushed my answer :)

Comment: @axiac: Didn't really look at the code that closely. But you're right, but based on the comments made by hd below my answer, and below the OP's question, I'd give him the benefit of the doubt, and correct the mistakes because I felt they were silly mistakes (by going too fast), rather than to down-vote in this case

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the updated code still doesn't work for the OP. They call `usort($this->out_table...)`. Notice the `$this` keyword. It runs in an object context, it's a method. `$field` is not global.

Comment: @axiac: That's because the OP's snippet contains a `$this->out_table`, but there's no code showing us where that `$this` is coming from. _that_ is not an error in the code here. The error message in the OP's question shows an unexpected T_FUNCTION token is causing the problem, and not `$this`, so it's safe to assume the code is part of a method, and therefore `$this->` is correct